# How change the Pie Menu Radius with python?

Tags: python, scripting, pie-menu

I want to change the pie menu radius using python, 
after some search I can access to that propertie using:

```
bpy.types.UserPreferencesView.bl_rna.properties['pie_menu_radius'].
```

but I can't change it

some help please! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And similar can be done for all other items on the User-Preferences -> Interface tab. (Warning doesn't update the visible value on the UI until you move your mouse, or trigger ui redraw some other way)

```
import bpy
prefs = bpy.context.user_preferences
prefs.view.pie_menu_radius = 80
```

Comment: Note that this may not work in an addon unless you use some hack to delay the execution until a valid context is available to change the user preferences!

Comment: Updated in 2.8x find under `context.preferences.view.pie_menu_radius`